# How to read a dataset in a .QRP file

Tags: delphi, dataset, quickreports

I have an ordinary .QRP file, and I want to read its dataset. Is it possible?

I'm using the following code to read the .QRP, but without success when I try to read its dataset.

```
var
  qrp : TQRPHandler;
begin
    qrp := TQRPHandler.Create;
        try
            qrp.Filename := 'D:\produção de pessoa fisica.QRP';
            qrp.Preview;
        finally
            qrp.Free;
        end;
```

Comment: When you say "without success", what do you mean, exactly?  Do you see a preview window but it is empty or what?

Comment: I can see the whole report, but I can't read the dataset. 
The preview does not matter for me, all I want is to read the dataset.

Comment: Tbh, I've no idea whether a .Qrp file stores the dataset data, or just some kind of image of the report.  What do the docs say?

Comment: As far as I know QuickReport components on their own do now allow direct comunication with database (you still need dataset component in your program). So I doubt having -qrp file alone would be enough for showing data from database. But I might be wrong. You should definitly check the Quick Report documentation about this.